# Resetting UIWebView Frame kills 75% of touchable area

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've got a webpage that is being viewed with a `UIWebView`.  It's got an input form, so I'm shifting the `UIWebView` up when the keyboard is summoned, and then moving it back down when the keyboard is dismissed, so that the selected input field is centered.  Code below:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    float offset = [self calculateYOffsetForKeyboard];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.05f options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^ {
        self.web.frame = CGRectMake(webView_rect_x, offset, self.web.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.web.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:nil];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification*) aNotification {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.05f options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^ {
        self.web.frame = CGRectMake(webView_rect_x, 0, self.web.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.web.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

**Here's the weird part:** when I do that (tap an input field to summon the keyboard then tap "Done" to dismiss it), everything but the top-left quarter of the `UIWebView` becomes untouchable.  It looks fine, animates up and down perfectly, displays the content properly, but anything right of or below the center point doesn't respond to touches (i.e. several buttons can't be pressed, etc).

Any idea why this might happen?  I've commented out lines and determined that it is the "self.web.frame" that is causing the problem: remove that movement and it works fine.  I've also `NSLog`'d the "self.web.scrollView.frame.size.width" and "self.web.scrollView.frame.size.height" values and they seem to be changing as expected and returning to normal.  Also the `calculateYOffsetForKeyboard` method is returning a proper value, (it changes based on which field is selected, but it's generally around -108.5).

So why would moving the frame back and forth alter the view's ability to respond to touches?  Any ideas?